# PostgreSQL, sum data from row of table?

Tags: postgresql

```
x a b c d
----------
A 1 2 3 4 
B 5 6 7 8 
C 6 7 8 9
```

I want my sum of A = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 and so for B and C, Is there any command that can sum row of data in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such built-in function, but you can simply do the following:

```
select x, a+b+c+d as column_sum from mytable
```

Assuming, of course, that the data type of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are numeric.